# How to create anonymous variables from a string?

Tags: prolog

I have defined a predicate `find_word/2` that when given a list of letters (with some letters possibly ungrounded), produces possible words that match the pattern given in the list. This is something like a [hangman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hangman_(game)) solver.

```
word('entity', n, 11).
word('physical entity', n, 1).
word('abstraction', n, 0).
% ... and 200,000 more entries ...

% Example: find_word([_,o,u,n,t,r,y], X) -> X = country
find_word(LetterList, Word) :-
    word(Word, _, _),
    atom_chars(Word, LetterList).
```

The code above works as intended. The challenge is that I receive hangman problems from outside the Prolog system as a string (e.g. `app_e`), where the underscores in the string represent the missing letters to be found by the prolog program above. i.e. I need to convert the `app_e` string into a list that can be fed into `find_word/2`.

On my first attempt, I used `atom_chars\2`:

```
?- atom_chars(app_e, L), find_word(L, Word).
```

Unfortunately, this does not work as hoped because `atom_chars(app_e, L)` -> `L = [a, p, p, '_', e]`. i.e. the `'_'` isn't a wildcard.

In summary, given a string `app_e`, how do I transform it into a list that can be fed into `find_word\2` to achieve the same effect as `find_word([a,p,p,_,e], Word).`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `atom_chars/2` is working as intended here, you just need a little cleanup step to finish turning your input into the desired form, which I think you can do quite straightforwardly like so:

```
charvar('_', _).
charvar(C, C) :- C \= '_'.
```

Usage looks like this:

```
?- maplist(charvar, [a,p,p,'_',e], X).
X = [a, p, p, _3398, e] .
```

Don't worry about the fact that this variable is not rendered as an underscore; your own probably wouldn't be either:

```
?- X=[_].
X = [_3450].
```